# Different subplots on different figures - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Any suggestions are appreciated.
I want to show 2 different figures with different subplots.

```
Ex:

% Figure 1, subplot 1
subplot(1,2,1); 
imshow(img1);
subplot(1,2,2); 
imshow(img2);

% Figure 2, subplot 2
subplot(1,2,1); 
imshow(img3);
subplot(1,2,2); 
imshow(img4);

% Also another Figure 3, with some image
figure, imshow(img5);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax is `figure(h)`, where `h` is the figure's handle which allows you to specify properties of the figure, including figure number (as explained [in Matlab reference](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/figure.html)).

If you only care about the figure number, you can just set `h` to the figure number (integer).

```
% Figure 1, subplot 1
figure(1);                 % this puts the upcoming subplots onto figure 1
subplot(1,2,1); 
imshow(img1);
subplot(1,2,2); 
imshow(img2);

% Figure 2, subplot 2
figure(2);                 % this puts the upcoming subplots onto figure 2
subplot(1,2,1); 
imshow(img3);
subplot(1,2,2); 
imshow(img4);

% Also another Figure 3, with some image
figure(3);                 % this puts the upcoming imshow onto figure 3
imshow(img5);
```